# Making an image cover a whole div of fixed height - Rails Carrierwave CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm working in a rails Instagram-like project where users can submit posts, each with a corresponding photo.

My objective now is to create a div that contains both a header (with some information) and a photograph. (

So my html.erb is something like this:

```
<div class="post-content">
  <div class="header">
   <!-- some other code here -->
  </div>
  <div class="photo-container">
    <%= image_tag(post.image_url, class:'img-responsive') %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The tricky bit is that:
1. I'd like to make the the "post-content" div of a particular 'fixed' size regardless of the size of image the user uploads.
2. The image to cover the whole "post-content" div without cutting out any overflow.
3. For the image to be responsive - I'm using Bootstrap.

So far my relevant scss code is like:

```
.post-content-panel {
  width: 60%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  // height: 300px; I'd like to fix this.
}  

.photo-container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This works partially. The image is responsive, covers the whole div but unfortunately the height of the parent div expands or retracts according to the image height.

I've tried to:
1. Fix the post-content-panel height but this 
2. Transform the image with transform: scale(0.5) but although the size is reduced the image doesn't cover the whole container div.
3. Standardise image sizes at upload in Carrierwave (gem I'm using in the backend). I used resize_to_fill and resize_to_fit without success (either the image is cut or it gets deformed.

How could I make this work. Is it a Carrierwave issue so I images are not cut when resized or could you see any css solution here regardless the size of the image. Thanks

Comment: You can only just use the post.image_url in a background-image and then apply background-size:cover in an inline style attribute on that div

Comment: Hi I don't thinks that's possible given that image file changes from post to post and as far as I understand all the methods to set a background image are done via the css code thus I'm not able to add the backend logic to it. Or am I misunderstanding your suggested approach?